# Main PC doesn't have the download speed as the other PCs, however, upload speed is normal

Tags: networking, router, internet, download, speed

So, recently, I've gotten a faster internet connection (80mb/10mb), but I've noticed that on my main PC, the download speed only goes up to about 30-45 mb, however the upload speed is at 9.5 mb. Here are the things I've tested.

- Trying out my internet connection with another PC. The other PC has 75 mb down and 9.8 mb upload speed.
- Plugging my main PC directly into the source, skipping the router. Same results.
- Updating firmware on the router (just to be sure).

I just can't seem to figure out what is eating away from my download speed. I've closed every app like Discord, TeamSpeak, etc., but my download speed hasn't gone up.

Comment: Is the pc connected via wired (ethernet) or wireless (wifi)?

Comment: Via ethernet. Both tests were run on wired connection.

Comment: Have you updated the network adapter driver on the PC? Which one is it?

Comment: I have a Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller as the network adapter, and it's up to date.

Comment: Run `ncpa.cpl`, right-click the adapter, Properties, Configure button, Advanced tab, in Properties list click on “Speed and Duplex” and ensure that the “Value” dropdown shows “1.0 Gbps Full Duplex”. Maybe try another cable. (Add to your answer `@harrymc` for me to be notified)

Comment: @harrymc I've tried that, and the results are sadly the same.

Comment: Only thing left is to try another adapter.

Comment: @harrymc And how would I go about that?

Comment: Usually an external adapter for USB.

Answer (score -1):

Software could be causing this issue. 
- Try disabling firewall, antivirus, anti-malware, redundant network drivers and any other auto start apps viewed from Task Manager. 
- You can also boot in to Safe Mode with Ethernet and verify the issue. 
- Visually inspect ethernet port for damage. 
- Look at output in CMD prompt of ipconfig /all for possible issue. 
- If you have a wifi connection also, disconnect it or remove it. 
- Change web browser, try fresh install of Firefox since its not based on Chromium 
- What is your ping and nslookup outputs? 
- Could be malware eating up resources. Boot into a USB Linux distro and test on that system to verify hardware or software issue.

Comment: I ran a speedtest in safe mode, and got the same results.